# What are the typical max speeds & g loads at which internal weapon bay(IWB) door can be opened for weapon deployment?

Tags: fighter, f-35, f-22

What are the typical numbers for popular aircraft like the F-22 & F-35 which have IWB?

Comment: I think it depends of the aircraft. Both mentioned fighters may have different values. If i were the guy making specifications, i would have asked for the bay to be openable for the whole flight envelope (up to max speed at 9G)